# mysql full text search contain words and phrase

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

How to make a mysql full text search, both contain "united state" and "railway"?

in [mysql full text boolean](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html), I see the if you want `find rows that contain both words`, do `+word_a +word_b` and if you want to contain the exact phrase, do `"some words"`, and In my case, how to do a right query? contain the words both match "united state", "railway", (NOT the case +united +state, that will cause also match: `+united +kingdom +state +policeman +railway`)

```
SELECT table as table_name,id,title,text 
FROM table 
WHERE (
MATCH (title,text) 
AGAINST ('+("united state") +railway' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)
```

This return zero results. But I am sure my table have some data match the query, and my table have already support full text, test search words `usa railway` run well. Thanks.

Comment: Is this work `'"united stated" +railway'` ?

Comment: @ajreal, this return all the result either `united stated` or `railway`, not exactly match.

Comment: how about break into two clause, `against ('"united state"') ... and against('+railway')`?

Comment: @ajreal, excuse me, how to write it? `AGAINST ('"united state"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND AGAINST ('+railway' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` ,return `#1064 You have an error in your sql syntax;....near `('+railway' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: you forget to include `MATCH(title,text) AGAINST () AND MATCH(title,text) AGAINST()`